# Discord.py: Adding someone to a discord server with just the discord ID

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add someone to a specific server and then DM said person with just the discord ID.

The way it works is that someone is logging himself in using discord `OAuth2` on a website and after he is logged in he should be added to a specific server and then the bot should DM saying something like `Welcome to the server!`

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to leave or join servers with OAuth2. Nor is it possible to DM a user on Discord with a bot unless they share a mutual server.